# Getter and Setters not working?

Tags: java, android, getter-setter

I've got two classes right now: RemindersDAO.java and ViewLocalReminders.java.

I'm trying to get access to a variable that's in ViewLocalReminders.java and I'm trying to call it from RemindersDAO.java. I'm doing this by using the getter/setter method combo. However, for some reason, my variable value keeps getting set to 0 in the getter method. Here's the code:

**ViewLocalReminders.java**

```
public class ViewLocalReminders extends SherlockListActivity {

private long reminderID;

    public void onCreate(Bundle SavedInstance) {

    reminderID = 16;
    setReminderID(reminderID);      

    }

    public void setReminderID(long id) {
        id = reminderID;
        System.out.println("Reminder ID Value in Setter: " + reminderID);
    }

    public long getReminderID() {
        return reminderID;
        System.out.println("Reminder ID Value in Getter: " + reminderID);
    }

}
```

**RemindersDAO.java**

```
public class RemindersDAO extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public Cursor getRowByID(Activity activity) {
    String[] from = { _ID, NAME };

    ViewLocalReminders viewLocalReminders = new ViewLocalReminders();
    long reminderID = viewLocalReminders.getReminderID();
    System.out.println("Value of Reminder ID in RemindersDAO: " + reminderID);

    }

}
```

This is the output that I'm getting for all my System.out.printlns:

1. Reminder ID Value in Setter: 16
2. Reminder ID Value in Getter: 0
3. Reminder ID Value in RemindersDAO: 0

So obviously, something's happening between the setter and getter methods. The value of reminderID is 16 in the setter method, the way it should be. However, the value goes to 0 in the getter method. Consequently, the value is still 0 when I call the getter method in RemindersDAO.java. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Thanks for all your help you guys. I wasn't able to figure out why my getters and setters weren't working, even though I followed all of your guys' suggestions. I'm guessing it has something to do with the fact that reminderID is taken in as an argument of a constructor. Either way, I solved my problem by using Android's Bundle and transferring my variables from one activity to another through that.

Again, thanks for all your help! :)

Comment: I guess you still don't understand, mate. Check my answered post here. I make a better detailed explanation on how getter-setter works and you'll find out why your code is wrong. I know you posted a question since 2012 but I wanna help you for a quick understanding about your bugs regarding getter-setter.

Comment: Also, once you read my answered post, I want you to recreate the same project before using with my corrected solution and compare with your mistake ones.

Answer (score 7):

here:

```
public void setReminderID(long id) {
    id = reminderID;  //<-- wrong, should be the other way around
    System.out.println("Reminder ID Value in Setter: " + reminderID);
}
```

You should use `reminderID = id` instead

Also:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle SavedInstance) {

    reminderID = 16;           //one of these two lines..
    setReminderID(reminderID); //..should do it      

}
```

No need to set the `reminderId` twice

Comment: I'll try it out and let you know. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: @user1666541 also you never call the `onCreate()`, if you want it to be called implecitly you should use a constructor (i updated my answer)

Comment: Oh no, this is an android project, so onCreate() is automatically called. I don't have to explicitly call it.

Comment: It's still not working. :/ I keep getting 0 as the value of reminderID. What's wrong?

Comment: @user1666541 I see then you should have added the `android` tag, or mention it in the question :)

Comment: @user1666541 verify when `onCreate()` is called, maybe it's called later.

Comment: No, onCreate() is being called properly... also, my question pertains mainly to the java logic that I'm using, so I didn't add an android tag. :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17156/discussion-between-user1666541-and-jidma)

Comment: Sorry I went to sleep :) please fix your getter, nothing should come after the return of the function.

Answer (score 2):

Your setter should look like this:

```
 public void setReminderID(long id) {
    reminderID = id;
    System.out.println("Reminder ID Value in Setter: " + reminderID);
}
```

Your `remainderID` variable should be on the left. The way you had it written, id was being set to reminderID.

Also, in your getter:

```
public long getReminderID() {
    return reminderID;
    System.out.println("Reminder ID Value in Getter: " + reminderID);
}
```

Since the `System.out.println` is after the return, then you shouldn't ever see the output. Return will end the function right there.

Answer (score 1):

you have

```
id = remainderID;
```

it should be

```
 remainderID = id;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're assignment of the reminder id is backwards

```
id = reminderID;
```

should read

```
reminderID = id;
```

in you `setReminderID` method

Answer (score 1):

```
public void setReminderID(long id) {
    this.reminderID = id;
    System.out.println("Reminder ID Value in Setter: " + reminderID);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try using this

```
this.remainderId = id;
```

instead of

```
remainderId = id;
```

in your model or domain.

Answer (score 0):

Your setter method seems wrong. You need to use your IDE's auto generation to create these methods.

Comment: No, they need to get it _right_.  You never _need_ to use an IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you accepted the answer. However, I think I know the problem about your getter-setter bug. It's about the order and order matters...it's like you're giving the instruction step-by-step.

Let me explain...

The first one, your setter method, did a mistake. (See marked comment/s)

```
public void setReminderID(long id) {
        id = reminderID; // --> your argument is id. reminderId field value should be changed not the other way around.
        System.out.println("Reminder ID Value in Setter: " + reminderID);
    }
```

Here's the correct setter.

```
public void setReminderID(long id) {
    reminderID = id; // --> "id" is your parameter and that's the reminderID's new value.
    System.out.println("Reminder ID Value in Setter: " + reminderID);
}
```

Next, about the getter. The reason why there's a bug in getter is because you have a wrong order. (See marked comment/s)

```
public long getReminderID() {
    return reminderID;
    System.out.println("Reminder ID Value in Getter: " + reminderID); // --> putting this line code after "return" results an error and therefore you won't be able to obtain a number or value!
}
```

Here's the correct getter. Look carefully the difference.

```
public long getReminderID() {
    System.out.println("Reminder ID Value in Getter: " + reminderID); // --> Anycode before "return" value will be fine.
    return reminderID; // --> Always put the "return" value at the last line within a getter method.
}
```

I hope you can use this correction for your future project in case whenever you need to apply the getter-setter method when you're programming. Remember that it's very important because ordering of the code matters and know where you direct the value changes. Questions?